# Google visualization timeline chart on web app

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, charts, google-visualization

I want to make a timeline chart based on values in google sheets and I am stuck....
I have no idea what can be wrong. The code seems to be fine but it's just me.

I guess the html side is not reading the array the way it should or it's not getting it at all.
In the spreadsheet I have only data that are needed for the chart. [timeLineData](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_Fyd93fW-BJxJ5OFUH3e-aogiVRnNW9ZrqVuu6JQ8yA/edit#gid=1430171921)

I want to pass to the chart data in the same order as it is in sheet. Start and End should be passed as a full date and time (I guess in this format new 'Date(0,0,0,12,0,0)' )

In console I am getting this kind of error:

> Uncaught  at myFunction (Kod:18)

and this

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Argument given to addRows must be either a number or an array
> at gvjs_G.gvjs_.Pp (jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:231)
> at drawChart (userCodeAppPanel:23)

and this

> Error An error occurred in the script, but there is no error code: Error: Cannot return an invalid date.
> at unknown function

The second error is probably because draChart function is not getting the data from the spreadsheet

code.gs

```
    function doGet(e) {
 
  Logger.log(e.parameter);
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index2");
     
}


function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("timeLineData");
  const srcValues = srcSheet.getRange('A2:D'+srcSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const newAr = srcValues.map(r=>[r[0],r[1],new Date(r[2]),new Date(r[3])]);
  Logger.log(newAr);
  return newAr;

}
```

and the html side:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  function cal2l(){
  
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(drawChart).myFunction();
  
  };
  
  google.charts.load("current", {packages:["timeline"]});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  
  function drawChart(newAr) {
    var container = document.getElementById('example3.1');
    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Machine' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Product' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
    dataTable.addRows(newAr);

    chart.draw(dataTable);
  }
</script>

<div id="example3.1" style="height: 200px;"></div>
    
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Just in case google documentation on timeline[Google](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline)

Can you please tell me what may be wrong?

Comment: Provide browser logs in dev console?

Comment: @TheMaster I edited a question and put console logs into it

Comment: Script Editor > View > Executions > Check  server logs at the timestamp

Comment: This is your culprit: `new Date()`. Don't forget that, unfortunately, you cannot pass them directly. As a neat trick, use `JSON.stringify` on the server-side and `JSON.parse` on the client-side (assuming you data structures survive serializaiton)

Comment: @TheMaster this is what I am getting now `Error An error occurred in the script, but there is no error code: Error: Cannot return an invalid date.
    at [unknown function](undefined)
`

Comment: @OlegValter I put a JSON into the code and now I am getting this error `Error: Type mismatch. Value 2020-10-26T23:00:00.000Z does not match type date in column index 2`

Comment: @Pimo - of course, that's why I mentioned the assumption - don't forget to construct `Date` objects from the UTC strings that result from stringification by passing them to a `Date()` constructor, and you should be all set

Comment: @OlegValter so I created something like this `const obj = JSON.parse(dane);
   const newAr = obj.map(r=>[r[0],r[1], Date(r[2]), Date(r[3])]);` is that what you meant? how and where should I use `Date()`? Because I am still getting  mismatch error

Comment: @OlegValter I got it! but now I have another problem... The timeline starts in 1980 but in the data I am putting in the "oldest" data is from 26 October 2020

Comment: @Pimo - well, it is likely that the date strings are incorrect - are you sure that what is passed is actually a UTC date string? Cause if it is `2020-10-26T23:00:00.000Z` then there should be no issue in parsing it back. Try logging the output, most likely something went wrong P.s. also note that constructors are invoked with `new` operator (try with and without and see the difference)

Comment: Also, my bad on the terminology up there, it is an *ISO* string, not a *UTC* string

Comment: @OlegValter Thanks! you helped me a lot! I am getting my timeline but I dont know why two headers from the spreadsheet are getting into array as well. I need to find a way to remove it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223989/discussion-between-oleg-valter-and-pimo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution thanks to @Oleg Valter who advised me to use JSON

May be someone find it useful:

code.gs

```
    function doGet() {
 

  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate();
     
}


function timelineData(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KzaKe9ShAZZAlK3CQC-UmrKzZXghNKAAx_pDHFX3YLI/edit#gid=0');
  const srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Array");
  const srcValues = srcSheet.getRange(2, 1, srcSheet.getLastRow()-1, 4).getDisplayValues()
  const newAr = srcValues.map(r=>[r[0],r[1], new Date(r[2]), new Date(r[3])]);
  
  const arr = JSON.stringify(newAr);
    
  return arr
}
```

And here you have HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
  
 <h1>機械別工程残</h1>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load("current", {packages:["timeline"]});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(getData);
  
  function getData(){
  
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(drawChart).timelineData();
  
  }
  
  function drawChart(dane) {
  //console.log(dane);
  const obj = JSON.parse(dane);
   const newAr = obj.map(r=>[r[0],r[1], new Date(r[2]), new Date(r[3])]);
    var container = document.getElementById('chart');
    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: '機械' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'オーダー' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
    dataTable.addRows(newAr);
    
    var options = {
     colors: ['#cbb69d', '#603913', '#c69c6e', '#e743f0', '#f04343', '#f0e443', '#b9f043', '#4ff043', '#43f0d9', '#435df0'],
     
     // timeline: { colorByRowLabel: true}
　　};
    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
  }
</script>

<div id="chart" style="height: 600px;"></div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```